# Get amount of read characters from formatted input operation

Tags: c++, io, stdin

I am reading numbers from an `istream`by using the `>>` operator overload. This works fine, but now I need to know how many characters have been consumed by that operation. I'm currently using something like

```
int startPos = in.tellg();
double number;
in >> number;
int readChars = in.tellg() - startPos;
```

This does work in some cases but it is quite fragile. When using `std::cin` as `in`, this doesn't work at all though (I assume that this is because `std::cin` doesn't have a position in the stream a it's potentially an endless one).

My question is (I think) rather simple: How can I get the amount of characters that have been read when using the `>>` operator?

During my search I encountered [gcount()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/) but this only works for unformatted input.
The documentation of the `>>` operator doesn't seem to give a hint on this either: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: I think you can't. But I may be wrong. Aside: the reason why it is not possible with stdin is not the right one, it is because `cin` may be connected to terminal input and you can't go backward, it is a pure stream.

Comment: why not converting your number to `std::string`  after reading, and getting its size ??

Comment: @ampawd You're forgetting about the decimal precision and the ignored whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

If the stream is formatted can't you just check the length of it?

Anways, `std::istream::operator>>` for C++ 98:

> **The function is considered to perform formatted input**: Internally, the function accesses the input sequence by first constructing a sentry object (with noskipws set to false). Then (if good), it extracts characters from its associated stream buffer object as if calling its member functions sbumpc or sgetc, and finally destroys the sentry object before returning.

For C++ 11:

> **The function is considered to perform unformatted input**: Internally, the function accesses the input sequence by first constructing a sentry object (with noskipws set to true). Then (if good), it extracts characters from its associated stream buffer object as if calling its member functions sbumpc or sgetc, and finally destroys the sentry object before returning.
> **The number of characters successfully read and stored by this function can be accessed by calling member gcount**.

So it seems that you can only count characters from unformatted input.

But:

> The unformatted input operations that modify the value returned by this function (`gcount()`) are: get, getline, ignore, peek, read, readsome, putback and unget.
>
> Notice though, that peek, putback and unget do not actually extract any characters, and thus gcount will always return zero after calling any of them.

So maybe you can use, for instance, `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);` or `std::istream::get` to get `gcount()` to count a formatted stream,

Comment: Checking the length of the stream won't do it. The stream may contain more than just that number so I won't always read the whole stream.

Comment: So essentially, you are saying that it's not possible to get the read chars from the >> operator directly?

Comment: @Raven, using `>> operator`, that I am aware of, no, you can always make your own function to get the string char by char, counting them.

Comment: Alright. Yeah I think this'll be what I'm going for. Writing some sort of wrapper class that takes care of counting...